# how to deconstruct array of json with different keys in postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm using postgres and I have a table like this:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{a:1},{b:2}] |
| 2 | [{a:1},{b:2}] |

I'm trying to retrieve a and b values with their id.

I tried this query

```
SELECT id,
 x.*
FROM table
cross join json_to_recordset(data::json) as x 
(   "a" varchar ,
    "b" varchar
)
```

but this retrieve it as

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| 1 | null | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | null |
| 2 | null | 2 |

is there a way to retrieve the id and its keys in one row?

Comment: Does your array always contain two elements? What if the first array element has the key `b` and the second one is `a`?

Comment: The correct solution however is to properly normalize your data model

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it always has these 2 keys. what do you mean by normalize my data model?

Comment: You should store "data" in a separate table containing two columns with a foreign key back to the main table. This is a text book example of a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is using *conditional aggregation* after quoting the key names as `"a"` and `"b"`

```sql
SELECT id, MAX(a) AS a, MAX(b) AS b
  FROM t,
       json_to_recordset(data::json) as j( "a" varchar, "b" varchar ) 
 GROUP BY id      
 ORDER BY id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=252930afd69ee5022c6badc4aafd777a)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can simply access each array element:

```
select t.id, 
      data -> 0 ->> 'a' as a,
      data -> 1 ->> 'b' as b
from the_table t
```